# Flutter: Get MaterialColor from a hex code

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Flutter app that loads a color hex code in a string from the shared preferences. I need to convert the hex code to a MaterialColor, which can be applied to the primarySwatch in the Scaffold widget. Is there a way I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

save you color like this as `String`:

```
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                  await prefs.reload();
                  prefs.setString('color', '0xff3B68FF');
```

and then read it like this:

```
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await prefs.reload();
String? obj = prefs.getString('color');
if (obj != null) {
  setState(() {
    colors = obj;
  });
}
```

then use it like this:

```
Theme(
          data: ThemeData(
              primarySwatch: MaterialColor(
            int.parse(colors),
            <int, Color>{
              50: Color(int.parse(colors)),
              100: Color(int.parse(colors)),
              200: Color(int.parse(colors)),
              300: Color(int.parse(colors)),
              400: Color(int.parse(colors)),
              500: Color(int.parse(colors)),
              600: Color(int.parse(colors)),
              700: Color(int.parse(colors)),
              800: Color(int.parse(colors)),
              900: Color(int.parse(colors)),
            },
          )),
          child: Row(),
    )
```